# Copy a string to clipboard using a script in Outlook 2007

Tags: vba, outlook, clipboard, outlook-2007

I'm building a script that will be fired by a rule in Outlook. The script is looking for a specific string in the body of the message and extracting some text.

I'd like to copy that text into the clipboard to use it in another application.

Here is my code:

```
Sub SaveAsText(MyMail As MailItem)

    Dim pos As String
    Dim loco As String

    pos = InStr(MyMail.Body, "message for Loco")
    loco = Mid(MyMail.Body, pos + 17, 8)

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I ran this Outlook 2003 macro:

```
Sub CopyToScratchPad()

  Dim DataToSave As New DataObject

  DataToSave.SetText "Test string"
  DataToSave.PutInClipboard

End Sub
```

I then opened NotePad and clicked Ctrl+C.  "Test string" appeared.

So, you can do what you want but is this really the best way of achieving your objective?